# Partial integration (not integration by parts), how is the following result obtained?

Tags: calculus, integration

Given we have these three equations:

$\frac{\partial^2w}{\partial x^2} = D_1$ (1)

$\frac{\partial^2w}{\partial y^2} = D_2$ (2)

$\frac{\partial^2w}{\partial x\partial y} = 0 $ (3)

Where $D_1$ and $D_2$ are constants.

The answer obtained by "integrating the three equations" as stated in the text is:

$w(x,y) = \frac{D_1}{2}x^2 + \frac{D_2}{2}y^2 + C_1x + C_2y + C_3$ (4)

My attempt is integrating each of the above expressions separately as follows:

Integrating (1) over x gives:

$w(x,y) = \frac{D_1}{2}x^2 + C_1(y)x + C_3(y)$ (5)

Integrating (2) over y gives:

$w(x,y) = \frac{D_1}{2}y^2 + C_2(x)y + C_4(x)$ (6)

Integrating (3) over x first and then y, and y first and then x gives:

$w(x,y) = C_1(y)x + C_3(y)$

And:

$w(x,y) = C_2(x)y + C_4(x)$

To obtain the answer (4), we can combine (5) and (6) by observation, and assuming $C_3$ and $C_4$ are equal but I don't think this is valid as we don't know this. How does one obtain (4)?

Comment: There must be a mistake. If we add (5) and (6), we get 2w = ... and combine C3 and C4 into a single constant C3(x,y). But then dividing by 2 will give D1/4x^2 and D2/4y^2, so I think this is an error

Answer (score 0):

No, $C_3$ is surely not $C_4$. You compare terms that only contain $x$, then terms only contain $y$, and then terms contain $x$ and $y$. That is:
$$\begin{align}
\frac{D_1}{2} x^2 &= C_4(x) \\
C_3(y) &= \frac{D_2}{2}y^2 \\
C_1(y)x &= C_2(x)y.
\end{align}$$
Since $C_1(y)x$ is linear in $x$, it follows $C_2(x)$ is also linear in $x$. In a similar way, you conclude that $C_1(y)$ is linear in $y$.
Thus, there exist reals $\tilde C_1, \tilde C_2$ such that
$$\begin{align}
C_1(y) &= \tilde C_2 y \\
C_2(x) &= \tilde C_1 x.
\end{align}$$